# R Shiny: Linking ggplot to slider bar per year

Tags: r, shiny

I've successfully put in a slider for the year and created a ggplot. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to filter the data by year (currently it shows for every year at once) as indicated by the slider bar.

How to obtain data:

```
library(WDI)
xdat <- WDI(indicator=c('NY.GNP.PCAP.CD', 'SH.DYN.MORT', 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'SP.DYN.LE00.IN', 'SP.DYN.TFRT.IN'), start=1960, end=2014, extra=TRUE)
sdata <- subset(xdat, xdata$region != "Aggregates")
sdata <- na.omit(sdata)

sdata$reg <- ifelse(sdata$region == "Europe & Central Asia (all income levels)", 1, ifelse(sdata$region == "Middle East & North Africa (all income levels)", 2, ifelse(sdata$region == "South Asia", 3, ifelse(sdata$region=="Latin America & Caribbean (all income levels)", 4, ifelse(sdata$region=="Sub-Saharan Africa (all income levels)", 5, ifelse(sdata$region=="East Asia & Pacific (all income levels)", 6, ifelse(sdata$region=="North America", 7, 0)))))))

sdata$col <- ifelse(sdata$reg == 1, "#FFFFFF", ifelse(sdata$reg == 2, "yellow", ifelse(sdata$reg == 3, "red", ifelse(sdata$reg== 4, "green", ifelse(sdata$reg== 5, "orange", ifelse(sdata$reg==6, "lavender", ifelse(sdata$reg== 7, "pink", 0)))))))
```

ui.r

```
library(googleCharts)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
  plotOutput("view"),
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  column(
         sliderInput("slider1", label=h3("Slider"),
                     min=1960, max=2014, value=50, sep="", animate=TRUE),
         ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
           radioButtons("radio", label=h3("Radio buttons"),
                        choices = list("Mortality" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), selected=1)),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(""),
      mainPanel("Main")
    ))
))
```

server.r

```
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(sdata, aes(x=NY.GNP.PCAP.CD, y = SP.DYN.LE00.IN)) +     geom_point(aes(size=pop^(0.75)/20000000+2, colour=col)) 
  })
})
```

The issue is that every year is showing up, and when I use the sliders, it doesn't do anything:

[image]

I'd also like to know how to use the radio buttons to change the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The ui.r is not working for me (EDIT: changed some tags) but I would guess something like this:

ui.r

```
library(googleCharts)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  plotOutput("view"),
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  column(4,
         sliderInput("slider1", label=h3("Slider"),
                 min=1960, max=2014, value=50, sep="", animate=TRUE)
     ),
 fluidRow(
  column(2,
       radioButtons("radio", label=h3("Radio buttons"),
                    choices = list("Mortality" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), selected=1)),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(""),
  mainPanel("Main")
  ))
))
```

and server

```
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderPlot({
    temp = sdata[sdata$year>(input$slider1)&sdata$year<2014,]
    ggplot(temp, aes(x=NY.GNP.PCAP.CD, y = SP.DYN.LE00.IN)) + geom_point(aes(size=temp$SP.POP.TOTL^(0.75)/20000000+2, colour=col)) 
  })
})
```

Comment: should work now, I saw you only vary the start input so `input$slider1` now selects the minimal year

Comment: Perhaps it is my ui.r?

Comment: I changed some column specs so the ui.r is working for me now. Not sure what the pop refers to in the `geom_point`, is it `sdata$SP.POP.TOTL` ?

Comment: Yes it is for that variable.

Comment: If you could put everything done (ui.r and server.r), that'd be a lifesaver.